# How can I split a span of days between two DateTimes into several one day spans?

Tags: c#, .net, datetime

I have a CSV file that I import into a `VehicleMovement` table. Each record is either a vehicle exit or entrance to a parkade, and after jumping through hoops while on fire, I have consolidated these into a `VehiclePresence` table, where nearly each record has both a `StartDateTime` and `EndDateTime`. Now I must calculate the parking charge for the length of the vehicle's presence. This is a problem when the presence spans more than one day. Parking prices are based on time of day, day of week, etc. so I need to split that presence into single day presences and calculate daily charges on them.

E.g. I have a cutover time of 06h00, and a `VehiclePresence` record where `StartDateTime` == **2013-04-22 20:37:28** and `EndDateTime` == **2013-04-25 22:55:20**. I would like to conjure up the following `VehiclePresenses`:

```
1. 04/22 20h37 to 04/23 06h00.
2. 04/23 06h00 to 04/24 06h00.
3. 04/24 06h00 to 04/25 22h55.
```

This will leave me with one original `VehiclePresence` record with modified start and end times, and two new records I will insert. This poses no problem.

How can I do this? I would personally just have one huge charge for over 24 hours, but I'm briefed to allow for all kinds of pricing rules.

Comment: Well, what have you tried so far? It seems to me that the first thing you'll need is a type to represent a from/to pair... And I suspect this will be most easily accomplished with an iterator block. You might also want to look at my [Noda Time](http://noda-time.googlecode.com) library for more pleasant date/time types than the BCL provides.

Comment: @JonSkeet I haven't tried too much, this project has been a brain strain and I should attack this problem in the morning. Just though I'd try now. I'm adding my code so far, and will look into Noda, thanks.

Comment: I assume that you mean that you would get four time spans in the example? Otherwise the last one will be more than 24 hours.

Comment: @Guffa Yes, I had not properly considered the fourth time span. That is where my brain gave up (it was very tired) and I asked the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calculate the first break time after the start time, and loop day after day until you reach the end time.

Example:

```
DateTime StartDateTime = new DateTime(2013, 04, 22, 20, 37, 28);
DateTime EndDateTime = new DateTime(2013, 04, 25, 22, 55, 20);

DateTime startTime = StartDateTime;

// calculate first break time
DateTime breakTime = StartDateTime.Date.AddHours(6);
if (breakTime < StartDateTime) {
  breakTime = breakTime.AddDays(1);
}

while (breakTime < EndDateTime) {

  Console.WriteLine("{0} - {1}", startTime, breakTime);

  // move to next day
  startTime = breakTime;
  breakTime = breakTime.AddDays(1);

}
Console.WriteLine("{0} - {1}", startTime, EndDateTime);
```

Output:

```
2013-04-22 20:37:28 - 2013-04-23 06:00:00
2013-04-23 06:00:00 - 2013-04-24 06:00:00
2013-04-24 06:00:00 - 2013-04-25 06:00:00
2013-04-25 06:00:00 - 2013-04-25 22:55:20
```

Comment: This is very similar to what I eventually came up with after a while. With the correct four items, not three. Thanks.